# Как в Qt4, переопределить QPlainTextEdit, так чтобы (1) показывался в редакторе форм и (2) компилировался?

Tags: c++, qt, override, qplaintextedit

Уточнено

1. После переопределения, и в файле .ui, замены на класс переопределённый, в интерфейсе объект перестаёт показываться (как его подключили для показа. не выполнением ли?).
2. В коде автоматически начинает в него добавляться QComboBox, хотя это не GroupBox, а QPlainTextEdit. Видимо редактор форм меняет под него исходник, будто бы его (QPlainTextEdit) больше нет.

   ```
    

    // Файл: IamOverQPlainTextEdit.h

    #ifndef IAMOVERQPLAINTEXTEDIT_H
    #define IAMOVERQPLAINTEXTEDIT_H

    #include 
    #include 

    class IamOverQPlainTextEdit : public QPlainTextEdit{
        public: IamOverQPlainTextEdit();
    };

    #endif // IAMOVERQPLAINTEXTEDIT_H

    
    

    // Файл: IamOverQPlainTextEdit.cpp

    #include "IamOverQPlainTextEdit.h"

    IamOverQPlainTextEdit::IamOverQPlainTextEdit(){

    }
   ```

```html
<widget class="IamOverPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
 <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
   <x>5</x>
   <y>5</y>
   <width>200</width>
   <height>400</height>
  </rect>
 </property>
</widget>
```

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit]). Пока непонятно даже на каком языке программирования вы делали (тут обычно с qt вопросы на с++ или питоне)

Comment: `</widget>` Лишний?

Comment: Нет. Поправлено